# Python list comparison to create trees

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have data in the following format:

```
Group  Item-1  Item-2
0       7       13
0      10        4
1       2        8
1       3        1
1       4        3
1       6       28
1       8        6
...
```

I need Python 2.7 to output growing chains/trees/connections between Item-1 and Item-2 for each group.  So for Group 0 other than 7-13 and 10-4, there are no chains/connections, but for Group 1 the output would be something like:

```
1  (2, 8, 6, 28), (4, 3, 1)
```

Comment: What is your specific problem? Coud you post the code you have developed so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to be a case for the union-find, or [disjoint-set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjoint-set_data_structure) algorithm. Here's an implementation I use to keep in my toolbox:

```
from collections import defaultdict

class UnionFind:
    def __init__(self):
        self.leaders = defaultdict(lambda: None)

    def find(self, x):
        l = self.leaders[x]
        if l is not None:
            l = self.find(l)
            self.leaders[x] = l
            return l
        return x

    def union(self, x, y):
        lx, ly = self.find(x), self.find(y)
        if lx != ly:
            self.leaders[lx] = ly

    def get_groups(self):
        groups = defaultdict(set)
        for x in self.leaders:
            groups[self.find(x)].add(x)
        return groups
```

And here how to apply it to your data:

```
# parse data
data = """Group  Item-1  Item-2
0       7       13
0      10        4
1       2        8
1       3        1
1       4        3
1       6       28
1       8        6"""
data = [[int(x) for x in line.split()] for line in data.splitlines()[1:]]

# get mapping {group_number: [list of pairs]}
groups = defaultdict(list)
for g, x, y in data:
    groups[g].append((x, y))

# for each group, add pairs to union find structure and get groups
for group, links in groups.items():
    union = UnionFind()
    for x, y in links:
        union.union(x, y)
    print group, union.get_groups().values()
```

Output is:

```
0 [set([10, 4]), set([13, 7])]
1 [set([1, 3, 4]), set([8, 2, 28, 6])]
```